# WPF .NET 5 simple error not caught by DispatcherUnhandledException Event

Tags: c#, wpf, unhandled-exception

For a test on unhandled exception I created following simple `.NET 5` project hoping that the global [DispatcherUnhandledException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception?view=net-5.0) Event would catch the error, but the error was raised locally and did not trigger the above event. **Question**: What I may be missing here, and how can we fix the issue. Maybe, a `VS2019` debug setting or something else?

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="Wpf_DeleteJuly21.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpf_DeleteJuly21"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button x:Name="btnTest" Content="Test" Width="26" Click="btnTest_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
namespace Wpf_DeleteJuly21
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string str = null;
            str.Trim(); //error would occur here.
        }
    }
}
```

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="Wpf_DeleteJuly21.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpf_DeleteJuly21"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" DispatcherUnhandledException="Application_DispatcherUnhandledException">
    <Application.Resources>
         
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**App.xaml.cs**

Error does NOT get caught here. According to [this](https://wpf-tutorial.com/wpf-application/handling-exceptions/) tutorial, as well, error should have been handled by this event, or else I may not be doing some thing right.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private void Application_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An unhandled exception occurred: " + e.Exception.Message, "Global Exception Test", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

**Error occurs at line** str.Trim() of btnTest_Click(...) event as follows:

[image]

Comment: As the exception popup clearly shows, you've enabled _"Break when this exception type is thrown"_. That's just the debugger doing its job. Uncheck that box if you don't want the first-chance break in the debugger (or _check_ the box under _"Except when thrown from:"_). See duplicate. Note that if you just continue from that point, your handler will be called just like you expected.

Answer (score -1):

Yes in debug mode, Exception dialog will catch the exception first. If you hit continue a few times, it will bubble up and caught by Application_DispatcherUnhandledException.

Or you can try to run without debug.